# Python extract single word in a complex string

Tags: python, string, split

In my project i have code that return strings like these ones:

`<Thread(Thread-11, started daemon 123145310715904)>`

`<Thread(Thread-12, started daemon 177145310715904)>`

`<Thread(Thread-12, started daemon 129145310715904)>`

I would to extract just "Thread-11" or "Thread-12" (in practice from first ( to first , char) part but i don't know how i can achieve this in python.
I tried with Split like this:

> tsplit = mystring.split('Thread-")

but i can return just what i wont.

Some help?

Thanks in advance
Luca

Comment: Regular expressions could be worth looking into.
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html.

Regular expressions will help you extract a string that matches a certain pattern, for example Thread-(number) or text between specific characters.

Comment: Looks like [repr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) of an object. Is `Thread` a class in your code? There might be cleaner ways to access `Thread-XX` instead of trying regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for this.

For you example what you could do is:

```
import re
pattern = "(Thread-\d+)"
text = "<Thread(Thread-12, started daemon 129145310715904)>"
match= re.search(pattern, text)
print(match.group(0))
```

output:

```
Thread-12
```

What this does is specifying something like "Search for a string that matches the pattern `Thread-<one or multiple numbers>`, in the `text` string".

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `split`, a way can be this:

```
a = '<Thread(Thread-11, started daemon 123145310715904)>'
p = a.split('(')[1].split(',')[0]
```

Output:

```
Thread-11
```

Answer (score 1):

```
inp = '<Thread(Thread-11, started daemon 123145310715904)>'
m = re.search('^.*\((.*),.*$', inp)
if m:
    print (m.group(1))
```

Comment: Maybe clarify that this extracts anything between an opening round parenthesis and a comma.

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex positive lookbehind:

```
In [144]: s = '<Thread(Thread-11, started daemon 123145310715904)>'

In [145]: re.search(r'(?<=\()[^,]+', s).group()
Out[145]: 'Thread-11'
```

- `(?<=\()` is zero-width positive lookbehind pattern that makes sure the match is preceded by `(`
- `[^,]+` matches one or more characters that are not `,`

Same thing with grouping (without lookbehind):

```
In [146]: re.search(r'\(([^,]+)', s).group(1)
Out[146]: 'Thread-11'
```

here we need to take the first captured group i.e. `group(1)` from the match object.

Answer (score 1):

@santi there are two ways you can extract what you want.

- using simple split
- using regex (the `re` module in python)

#### Example 1 using `str.split()`

```
string = '<Thread(Thread-11, started daemon 123145310715904)>'
out = string.split(',')[0].split('Thread(')[1]
print(out)
```

#### Example 2 using `re`

```
import re
string = '<Thread(Thread-11, started daemon 123145310715904)>'
out = re.search(r'(Thread-\d+)', string)
print(out.group())
```

if using threads then thread name can also be printed / returned using `.name` ro `.getName()`

#### Example.

```
>>> from threading import Thread
>>> def somefunc():
        print('hello')
>>> thread = Thread(target=somefunc)
>>> thread.daemon= True
>>> thread.start()
>>> thread.name, thread.getName() # gives thread names directly
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple regex -

```
import re
word = re.search(u"[(][a-zA-Z]{6}[-]\d+[,]", "<Thread(Thread-11, started daemon 123145310715904)>").group(0).replace("(", "").replace(",", "")
# OP 'Thread-11'
```

Explanation of this pattern -

```
[(][a-zA-Z]{6}[-]\d+[,]
[(] - match a parentheses 
[a-zA-Z]{6} - match strings, 6 occurrences 
[-] - match a hyphen
\d+[,] - match digits and then match a hyphen
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know in advance the position of your element in the character string, you can use the slices:

```
>>> result = "<Thread(Thread-12, started daemon 129145310715904)>"
>>> result = result[8:17]
>>> result
'Thread-12'
```

This solution is more rigid than the others, but can be much simpler to apply depending on the need.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is

```
str1 = '<Thread(Thread-11, started daemon 123145310715904)>'
import re
m = re.search('Thread-\d\d', str1)
m.group(0)
```